# SQL where clause two seperate values?

Tags: mysql, sql

so for an assignment I need to *Find the manager(s) of the employee(s) who support customer(s) from Canada* from the [chinook data base](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/)

For now I have the following code:

```
select distinct employee.LastName, employee.EmployeeId, employee.ReportsTo
from customer,
     employee
where customer.Country = 'Canada'
  and customer.SupportRepId = employee.EmployeeId;
```

So I get the following results
[image]

So I need to get the names of the general manager whose EmployeeId is 2, but I don't know how to put it into one query.

This is an overview of all the employees:
[image]

This is an overview of all the customers:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You might be surprised how many questions are passed over because they aren't self contained and expect us to chase down links. Moving on.

Comment: Can I see `customer` table ?

Comment: Do not use the old variant of joining tables in the where statement. Use the `join` keyword

Comment: @Jens agree with it

Comment: Also show the sample data the expected result and the result you get as text not as link

Comment: You linked an sqlite database but tag with mysql. Do you really whant a mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the the employee table twice:

```
select distinct employee.LastName, employee.EmployeeId, manager.Lastname
from 
 customer 
 join     employee as employee on customer.SupportRepId = employee.EmployeeId
 join employee as manager on employee.ReportsTo = manager.employeeId
where customer.Country = 'Canada'
```